# A particle traveling with velocity $v_a $ in the medium $A$ and with velocity $v_b $in the medium $B$

Tags: derivatives, optimization

A particle traveling with velocity $v_a $ in the medium $A$ and with velocity $v_b $ in the medium  $B$. The particle starts at time $t = 0$ from the point $P_i$ and has to get in the minimum time to the point $P_j$.

How can i determine the trajectory that this particle must follow to reach the point $P_f$ in minimum time.

[image]

Some help to  formulate the equation for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that no force is acting on the particle, the time to go from $P_i$ to $P_j$ is $$T=\frac{l_{P_iP}}{v_a}+\frac{l_{PP_j}}{v_b}$$ where $P$ is some point at the interface between the two mediums and $l_{P_iP},\ l_{PP_j}$ denotes their lengths. Now, let the Interface denotes $x$ axis and the points $P_i,P_j$ have coordinates $(0,h),\ (s,-m)$ respectively. Let $P$ has coordinate $(x,0)$. Then $$l_{P_iP}=\sqrt{x^2+h^2},\ l_{PP_j}=\sqrt{(x-s)^2+m^2}$$ So, $T$ is minimized if $\frac{dT}{dx}=0,\ \frac{d^2T}{dT^2}>0$. Then, $$\frac{dT}{dx}=0\Rightarrow \frac{x}{v_a\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}+\frac{x-s}{v_b\sqrt{(x-s)^2+m^2}}=0\\ \Rightarrow \frac{\sin \theta_i}{v_a}=\frac{\sin \theta_r}{v_b}$$ where $\theta_i,\ \theta_r$ are the angles of incidence and refraction respectively. You can perhaps recognize this result. It is Snell's law of refraction, which is actually based upon [Fermat's principle of least time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle). Hope your question is answered.

Comment: really ty!!!, now i understand it :D

Comment: excuse me, i understand all your analyzes but why $$\frac{dT}{dx}=0\Rightarrow \frac{x}{v_a\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}+\frac{x-s}{v_b\sqrt{(x-s)^2+(h+m)^2}}=0\\ implies \frac{\sin \theta_i}{v_a}=\frac{\sin \theta_r}{v_b} ?$$

Comment: i found that the trajectory in minimum time is $ T = \frac{h}{v_a} + \frac{h+m}{v_b}$ its that correct ?

Comment: Sorry previously I made a mistake writing $h+m$ instead of $m$. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: I do not know the correct answer but it seems that the solution to the equation obtained by differentiation is going to be pretty messy because you need to solve a degree $4$ equation.